# Intellij Typescript compiler doesn't know TResult type

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I'm running Intellij 2017.1.5 with its internal Typescript 2.4.1 compiler. The compiler complains:

> Error:(322, 58) TS2339:Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'.

It seems to me that the type TResult used by lodash is not known. Is that a language/Typescript library type?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the latest type definitions of lodash, the function get is defined as follows:

```
    get<TResult>(
        object: any,
        path: StringRepresentable|StringRepresentable[],
        defaultValue?: TResult
    ): TResult;
```

By default TResult means nothing, other than the fact that defaultValue and the return type must be the same. However in case you don't have a defaultValue, you could also tell the compiler what TResult should be by calling `_.get` with the expected result type. So something like `_.get<Option[]>(state, 'roomcodes.selectedOptions').map...`